# Opening public socket with python in Cloud9

Tags: python, sockets, udp, cloud9-ide

I am trying to make a simple and very low level UDP server on Cloud9.
What I would like to do is to open an UDP socket on some port and some ip so that it is accessible from the extern and so that I can get an incoming UDP packet.

I tried to do something like

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("", 12345))
```

But then I wouldn't know the ip. I naively tried to do an `ifconfig` but I got an ip that I couldn't even ping.

I found out about the `IP` and `PORT` environment variables, but `IP` is always `0.0.0.0`.

Is there any way to do what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint you, but that is not possible. At this moment only TCP port 8080 in the workspace can be accessed from the internet. So you can develop the UDP server and test its functionality from the same workspace, but to make it work from external sources you should deploy the code to a hosting provider.

Comment: Sorry to hear that! Thank you very much!